# JSF custom converter not always used

Tags: java, jsf, converters, jsf-1.2

I've got a custom converter that extends DateTimeConverter, which I've registered for the java.util.Date class in my faces-config.xml. Essentially all that the new converter is doing is adding a more descriptive message and passing it to the current context so that it can be displayed in the appropriate jspf.

For one date field on the screen I'm testing, everything works fine; for the other two, my getAsObject() method is never called. However, I've added an h:messages tag for debugging and the other two date fields are throwing conversion errors, so they're still attempting conversion somewhere.

There's no difference I can find between the three fields; they all use the same styleclasses, and each is backed by a java.util.Date. I think what's happening is that the second two are using the default converter, but I'm not sure why. The fields are all dynamically created so I cannot add a tag in the jsp, but I did try explicitly setting the converter in my utility class where the component is created, but had the same issue.

Any ideas what I should look for? I feel like it's something small and obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

**EDIT :**
There's really not that much going on with the parts I can easily copy+paste. In the jsp, there's a dataTable (the on that works) :

```
<h:dataTable id="myTableID" binding="#{myBackingbean.myTable}" value="#{myBackingbean.myInfoArray}"
    rowClasses="#{myBackingbean.myRowClasses}" columnClasses="field-first,field-last" var="varDetails" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
    headerClass="sub-heading ui-widget-header" width="98%">
</h:dataTable>
```

Where myTable is an HtmlDataTable and myInfoArray is a linked list of one of our classes.

The other two :

```
<h:dataTable id="myTableID2" binding="#{myBackingbean.myTable2}" value="#myBackingbean.myInfoArray2}" 
    rowClasses="#{myBackingbean.myRowClasses2}" columnClasses="field-first,field-last" var="varDetails2" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
    headerClass="sub-heading" styleClass="" width="100%">
</h:dataTable>
```

In my utility class :

```
HtmlInputText dateInput = new HtmlInputText();
dateInput.setId("dynamic_Date");
ValueBinding binding_value_3_3 = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.dtValue}");
dateInput.setValueBinding("value", binding_value_3_3);
ValueBinding bindingCol_3_4 = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.date}");
dateInput.setValueBinding("rendered", bindingCol_3_4);
ValueBinding bindingCol_date = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.disabled}");
dateInput.setValueBinding("disabled", bindingCol_date);

HtmlInputText dateTimeInput = new HtmlInputText();
dateTimeInput.setId("dynamic_DateTime");
ValueBinding binding_value_11_3 = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.strValue}");
dateTimeInput.setValueBinding("value", binding_value_11_3);
ValueBinding bindingCol_11_4 = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.dateTime}");
dateTimeInput.setValueBinding("rendered", bindingCol_11_4);
ValueBinding bindingCol_dateTimeInput = getApplication().createValueBinding("#{XXXXXXXX.disabled}");
dateTimeInput.setValueBinding("disabled", bindingCol_dateTimeInput);

column1.getChildren().add(dateInput);
column1.getChildren().add(dateTimeInput);
```

Where XXXXXXXX is either varDetails or varDetails2.

Comment: At least post the JSF code which gives the problem in order to reproduce it and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue was; I ended up just creating a new project, which cleared it up.